# How can we extract region bound by a contour in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am new to OpenCV and I was trying to extract the region bound by largest contour. It may be a simple question, but I am not able to figure it out. I tried googling too, without any luck.

Answer (score 5):

I would:

1. Use `contourArea()` to find the largest closed contour.
2. Use `boundingRect()` to get the bounds of that contour.
3. Draw the contour using `drawContours()` (with thickness set to -1 to
   fill the contour) and use this as a mask.
4. Use use the mask to set all pixels in the original image not in the
   ROI to (0,0,0).
5. Use the bounding rectangle to extract just that area from the
   original image.

Comment: I was trying to use this approach. I am using python. I tried drawing the contour on a blank image and filling it with white. Then I tried doing a bitwise_and, but it was giving errors saying the type did not match.
I am not sure what you are talking about when you say mask using it.

Comment: I found my mistake. In python opencv image is implemented as a numpy array of uint8. But the mask I was creating was an array of floats. So when I fixed it, I was able to do a bitwise_and. Thanks for help nonetheless :)

Answer (score 1):

[**Here**](http://harismoonamkunnu.blogspot.it/2013/06/opencv-find-biggest-contour-using-c.html) is well explained what do you want do develop.

Basically you have to:

- apply threshold to a copy of the original image;
- use findContours -> output is:

  ```
  vector<vector<Point>>
  ```

  that stores contours;
- iterate on contours to find the largest.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had already found the largest contour. The problem is that I am not able to extract the region which lies inside.